# IKEv2 mutual authentication step

Tags: authentication

I read from here that,
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296

it mentioned,

2.15.  Authentication of the IKE SA

the initiator
signs the first message (IKE_SA_INIT request), starting with the
first octet of the first SPI in the header and ending with the last
octet of the last payload.  Appended to this (for purposes of
computing the signature) are the responder's nonce Nr, and the value
prf(SK_pi, IDi').  It is critical to the security of the exchange
that each side sign the other side's nonce.

from part one(IKE_SA_INIT request), we have Ni, then we append Nr,

why we need to append the third part: prf(SK_pi, IDi') and then sign the msg?

why just signing Ni and Nr is not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why just signing Ni and Nr is not enough?

Because we want to make sure that man-in-the-middle can modify (or hijack) the initial messages without being detected.

Consider this attack:

- Alice sends an IKE_SA_INIT request to Bob
- Mallet intercepts that message; he forwards his own IKE_SA_INIT message to Bob, using Alice's Ni value, but his own KE payload
- Bob replies with an IKE_SA_RESP message, which his Nr value.
- Mallet intercepts that message; he forwards his own IKE_SA_RESP message to Alice, using Bob's Nr value, but his own KE payload

Essentially, Mallet is establishing two separate IKE connections, one with Alice and one with Bob.

Alice then authenticates herself; if she just signed the Ni, Nr values she saw, Mallet could just resend that signature to Bob (which saw the exact same Ni, Nr) values, and so Bob would assume he's talking to Alice.

By appending the prf(SK_pi, IDi') value, this is not possible (because Alice and Bob don't have the same SK_pi value)

Comment: thx for the clear explanation! one more question, in IKE_SA_INIT, the nonce Ni, Nr are exchanged without encryption, in this case, is this meant using SK_pi for mutual auth will not work? thanks for insight!

Comment: @pianobegginer: I can't parse your question; the point I was making above is that SK_pi is a function of the two KE payloads exchanges; those must be different (Mallet cannot just forward the ones that Alice and Bob sent, he needs to send ones for which he knows the private keys), and so (in the unmodified IKE protocol) he can't just forward the AUTH payload (as it would not authenticate)

Comment: sorry, let me clarify a bit further: (1) in IKE_SA_INIT, the nonce Ni and Nr are exchanged without encryption, so Ni and Nr is public information? Is it any impact to IKE security? (2)  Alice and Bob have secret DH values and SK_pi  is derived from it (nonce+DH value), so only Alice and Bob know this KE payload, Mallet will not know, this prevent man-in-middle attack.is this right?

Comment: @pianobegginer: 1) having Ni, Nr public is not a security issue, and 2) that is not quite correct; in the attack I described, Mallet knows the SK_pi he shares with Alice and the one he shares with Bob, hence it being secret is not key to preventing man-in-the-middle.  Instead, the man-in-the-middle attack is prevented because Mallet cannot generate the AUTH payload that is supposed to come from Bob (to Alice) and from Alice (to Bob), and he can't forward the AUTH payload he received (because that is based on a different SK_pi value)

Comment: digesting, thx for the patience of explanation. one more question, "initiator signs the first message", so the initiator use "SK_ai" to sign the message of "Ni,Nr,prf(SK_pi, IDi')", how is this signature done? HMAC with SK_ai? thanks.

Comment: @pianobegginer: the signature is generated either by generating a signature using the initiator's public key, or a MAC based on a preshared key (as detailed later in that section)

Comment: sorry for asking further, my questions becomes: why have to sign Ni and Nr? it seems just signing prf(SK_pi) is enough? thx

Comment: very appreciated if you could give some comments on whether just signing prf(SK_pi) is enough? because SK_pi is derived from Ni and Nr. thx a lot.